# JTable: without rows, height size wrong

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem with my `JTable`. It is new and not have a row but when I run the project, I see this:

[image]

and not understand why it is square.

This is `JPanel` class

```
public class PanelTF extends JPanel implements Serializable, ActionListener, MouseListener
{
private JPanel pan_4 = new JPanel();
private JPanel pan_g = new JPanel();    
private TableModel tModel;
private JTable table;
private JScrollPane JSPTTable;

public PanelTF()
{
/* ... */
tModel=new TableModel(sinTv.getListTv());
table=new JTable(tModel);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

for (int i=0; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++)
{
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
}

table.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
JSPTTable = new JScrollPane(table);
pan_4.setBackground(Color.yellow);
pan_4.add(JSPTTable);
pan_g.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pan_g,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
pan_g.add(pan_4);
}
```

This is my `TableModel` Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel 
{
    private ArrayList<IFS> listaMista;

    public TableModel(ArrayList<IFS> listaMista) 
    {
        this.listaMista = listaMista;
    }

    public int getRowCount() 
    {
        return listaMista.size();
    }

    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
        return 9;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) 
    {
        switch (column) 
        {
            case 0: return "Tipo";
            case 1: return "Titolo";
            case 2: return "Alias";
            case 3: return "Regista";
            case 4: return "Num. Ep";
            case 5: return "Ep1";
            case 6: return "Ep2";
            case 7: return "Ep3";
            case 8: return "A. inizio";
            case 9: return "A. fine";           
        }
        return "";
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int column) 
    {
        switch (column) 
        {
            case 0: return IFS.class;   // tipo
            case 1: return String.class;    // titolo
            case 2: return String.class;    // alias
            case 3: return String.class;    // regista  
            case 4: return Number.class;    // numEp
            case 5: return String.class;    // ep1  
            case 6: return String.class;    // ep2
            case 7: return String.class;    // ep3
            case 8: return Number.class;    // anno inizio 
            case 9: return Number.class;    // anno fine 
        }
        return Object.class;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
    {
        IFS ifs = listaMista.get(row);
        if(ifs instanceof SerieTv)
        {
            SerieTv serie=(SerieTv) ifs;
            switch (column) 
            {
                case 1: return serie.getTitolo();
                case 2: return serie.getAlias();
                case 3: break;  // auto-boxing!
                case 4: return serie.getNumEp();    // auto-boxing!
                case 5: return serie.getEp1();  // auto-boxing!
                case 6: return serie.getEp2();  // auto-boxing!
                case 7: return serie.getEp3();  // auto-boxing!
                case 8: return serie.getAnno(); // auto-boxing!
                case 9: return serie.getAnnoFine(); // auto-boxing!
            }
        }
        if(ifs instanceof FilmTv)
        {
            FilmTv filmtv=(FilmTv) ifs;
            switch (column)
            {
                case 1: return filmtv.getTitolo();
                case 2: return filmtv.getAlias();
                case 3: return filmtv.getRegista(); 
                case 8: return filmtv.getAnno();
            }
        }
        if(ifs instanceof Film)
        {
            Film film=(Film) ifs;
            switch (column)
            {
                case 1: return film.getTitolo();
                case 2: return film.getAlias();
                case 3: return film.getRegista();   
                case 8: return film.getAnno();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) 
    {
        IFS ifs = listaMista.get(row);
        if(ifs instanceof SerieTv)
        {
            SerieTv serie=(SerieTv) ifs;
            switch (column) 
            {
                case 1: serie.setTitolo((String) value); break;
                case 2: serie.setAlias((String) value); break;
                case 3: break;
                case 4: serie.setNumEp((Integer) value); break;
                case 5: serie.setEp1((String) value); break;
                case 6: serie.setEp2((String) value); break;
                case 7: serie.setEp3((String) value); break;
                case 8: serie.setAnno((Integer) value); break;
                case 9: serie.setAnnoFine((Integer) value); break;
            }
        }
        if(ifs instanceof FilmTv)
        {
            FilmTv filmtv=(FilmTv) ifs;
            switch (column) 
            {
                case 1: filmtv.setTitolo((String) value); break;
                case 2: filmtv.setAlias((String) value); break;
                case 3: filmtv.setRegista((String) value); break;
                case 8: filmtv.setAnno((Integer) value); break;
            }
        }
        if(ifs instanceof Film)
        {
            Film film=(Film) ifs;
            switch (column) 
            {
                case 1: film.setTitolo((String) value); break;
                case 2: film.setAlias((String) value); break;
                case 3: film.setRegista((String) value); break;
                case 8: film.setAnno((Integer) value); break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void aggiungi(IFS ifs) 
    {
        listaMista.add(ifs);
        int row = listaMista.size() - 1;
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row); 
    }
}
```

Any idea to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `JScrollPane` that you wrap the table with. When you do this, the pane get the `preferredViewportSize` which is defaulted to 450x400.

You can override it, if you don't want it that big

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    }
};
```

You could also add the table header and table separately to a panel. That way the table will not has a preferred size for the container. Something like

```
String[] cols = {"col", "col", "cols" };
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{}, cols);
panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(table);
```

The problem with this approach, is you need to consider the dynamic nature of the table. When you add rows, you need the containing panel to keep resizing. The JScrollPane is sizes for that reason. So the layout doesn't get all messed up when rows are added. Hence, the preferred view port size, so your layout is set and you don't have to worry about dynamic resizing